# Pass param to xslt as node in apache camel

Tags: xslt, apache-camel

Is it possible to pass param as node not as string?

camel context:

```
<setHeader headerName="document_as_node">
    <simple>${body}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:param name="document_as_node" />
```

body is a xml document, but I'm passsing it as string (I got error when I'm trying to use this param in xpath). How can I pass this as node or how can I transform it?

Comment: Are you want insert node(in header) into current xml ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example will help:

```
from("timer:foo?period=30s")
            .setBody(constant("<oldWrapTag><someTag>123</someTag></oldWrapTag>"))
            .convertBodyTo(org.w3c.dom.Document.class)
            .setBody(xpath("//someTag"))
            .setHeader("insert", simple("body"))
            .to("xslt:/xslt/test.xsl")
            .to("log:body?showBody=true")
    ;
```

xslt :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="insert"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="wrapTag">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$insert"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
2018-10-24 14:03:07,952 | INFO  | 10 - timer://foo | body                             | 247 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wrapTag><someTag>123</someTag></wrapTag>]
```